# Stata- How to combine a multiple choice set of variables into one

Tags: stata

My group and I are new to Stata and have been tasked with creating our own market research project. For one question on our survey, we asked participants to click on every subject that interested them from a set of 9 choices (and a write in option). After we downloaded our dataset from Qualtrics, we found that this had created ten 'course interest' variables; each being one of the selected choices from each unique-identifier participant.

The data is categorical and lists '1' for being interested and '.' for not selecting.

We hoped to create one variable out of these by using the `egen` command but it doesn't seem to combine them correctly:

```
egen total_interest = rowtotal(course_interest_1 course_interest_2 course_interest_3 course_interest_4 course_interest_5 course_interest_6 course_interest_7 course_interest_8 course_interest_9 course_interest_11), missing
```

This creates a variable with some strange frequencies. When you `codebook` the results it lists:

```
 Tabulation: Freq.  Value
                         
102  1

16  2

2  3

5  4

1  7

4  .
```

Whereas for e.g. `course_interest_1`, there are 32 '1' responses and 98 '.' responses.

This data is vital for conducting a regression and we are stuck without it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks wrong to me on this evidence.

The `codebook` results for your total variable imply 126 people showed some interest -- making one or more choices --and 4 showed no interest in any. That doesn't contradict what is said in your question about `course_interest_1`.

For a fuller view of your data, go

```
tabstat course_interest_*, s(n sum) c(s)
```

Missings will be ignored in calculating the sum, so the sum will be the number of 1s,  which should be the same as n.